# Manual edit of SyncedRules.plist not sticking

Tags: macos, mail.app, high-sierra, mail-rules

I have a number of Mail.app rules whose action is to move the message to mailbox A. I just created a new mailbox B that I want them to move to instead.

Doing this by hand is very tedious. Also, there's a bug in the rule editor that causes the list of actions to shift up each time I edit one of them, and after doing a few rules the dropdown with the list of rules is moving out of the little window so I can't click on it.

So I quit out of Mail.app and loaded `~/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/SyncedRules.plist` into a text editor (Emacs in my case) and went through this, changing

```
        <key>CopyToMailboxURL</key>
        <string>imap://username@mail.company.com/A</string>
```

and

```
        <key>MailboxURL</key>
        <string>imap://username@mail.company.com/A</string>
```

to

```
        <key>CopyToMailboxURL</key>
        <string>imap://username@mail.company.com/B</string>
```

and

```
        <key>MailboxURL</key>
        <string>imap://username@mail.company.com/B</string>
```

in all the relevant rules.

But when I restarted Mail.app, all the rules I modified reverted to their old actions. How do I get my manual changes to be used?

I don't have iCloud syncing enabled for Mail, so I don't think it should be in iCloud.

Every rule has a field like this:

```
        <key>TimeStamp</key>
        <integer>96332387</integer>
```

with the same number.

Do I need to increment that so it will know that the rule changed on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6?

UPDATE:

I tried using

```
defaults read com.apple.mail
```

This has lots of preference settings, but it doesn't include the rules.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `defaults read ... ` [(or export)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231034/) and `defaults write ...` so that you can change the preferences in the database which notifies Mail when running that the preferences have changed and persist them to storage?

Comment: How would I use that? `defaults read ~/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/SyncedRules.plist` says `Domain /Users/barmar/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/SyncedRules.plist does not exist`

Comment: Exactly - you're not getting to where Mail is storing things - you want to avoid thinking of the filesystem and discover where Mail stores these - whether they are stored in system / iCloud / user domain is up to the programmer - not us. `defaults read com.apple.mail` is where I'd start, but I don't have mail rules - so my results won't help you

Comment: My research has told me that this is where the rules are stored. Whenever I exit Mail, it gets rewritten, and I can see all my criteria and actions in it.

Comment: If I should be using `defaults` to update them, I need to know the domain and keys.

Comment: I'm letting you know your research may be wrong or out dated. See the defaults read above to get started. Yes you do - the question may be " what domain does Mail save these" and not How to I edit these files - this is a wonderful example of an XY problem - you're asking how to do an intermediate step that may be the wrong way forward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113615/discussion-between-barmar-and-bmike).